# Find the probability that when n balls are extracted, between a and b of them are white

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> An urn contains white and black balls with $p_w = p$ and $p_b = 1-p$. If we made $n$ extractions with replacement what is the probability that the number of white balls extracted is between $a$ and $b$?

I thought this:

- $P=P(b) - P(a)$
- $P(b) =
     \binom{n}{b}\cdot\left(p\right)^{b}\cdot\left(1-p\right)^{n-b}$
- $P(a)
     = \binom{n}{a}\cdot\left(p\right)^{a}\cdot\left(1-p\right)^{n-a}$

Am I doing it right?

Comment: No. You should do cumulative up to b minus cumulative up to a. Not just P(b)-P(a). The result is $$\sum_{k=a}^b\dbinom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Comment: It's nothing to do with $P(b) - P(a)$. If you think about it in cases, what you really need to do is add up $P(a) + P(a + 1) + ... + P(b)$ which is equal to the summation expressed by Jimmy R.

Comment: Just to emphasize:  there is no reason for $P(b)-P(a)$ to be positive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I think about the shape of the binomial distribution it could be that $P(b) - P(a)$ be negative, but this is in contrast with $0\leq p \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be slightly careful with this situation, since we are looking
for multiple sample points, not just the sample points that our extraction
gives us $b$ white balls and our extraction gives us $a$ white balls.

What
we are looking for is
$P(a \leq X \leq b)$, where $X \sim Binom(n,p_w)$ is the random variable
representing the number of white balls picked.

By the cumulative mass
function of the binomial distribution,
$P(a \leq X \leq b) = \sum_{i = a}^b \binom{n}{i} p^i (1-p)^{n-i}.$
You can simplify this using  the binomial theorem.